# In javascript / html, can I point open and save file dialogs at a particular directory on a local (native) file system?

Tags: javascript, html, file, directory, dialog

In a JavaScript+HTML environment, I present the user with open and save file dialogs.  I know of two basic ways to do this, one using an input element, the other using the Native File API.  Both do what they were designed to do.

However, I would **really** like to have these dialogs pointing at a particular directory when they open.  Fairly extensive investigation has turned up no way to do this.

Is this a lost cause?  I'd willingly limit my app to chromium offspring if doing so would allow me to accomplish this with a chrome extension...

Comment: JavaScript has no control of the file dialog.  But I wonder would drag and drop be more useful for your use case?  Users could then just create a link to the directory, and then drag drop from there.

Comment: @Keith: thanks for your response.  Here's a bit more about my case--my JavaScript edits the HTML it was invoked by, and what I want to do is save the HTML back to its original location, without forcing the user to navigate there.  And since this is not just one HTML file being edited, but any number of them (not all at once, of course), it becomes quite burdensome if you are forced to navigate back to the original directory every time you need to save your work.

Comment: @Keith: Granted that JavaScript has no control of the file dialog, I'm wondering if there is some other way to influence the browser's choice of initial directory for dialogs.  If, for example, the save dialog always opens pointing at the folder where the last download/save occurred, is there a way to influence the browser there?   I haven't found it yet, but I'm still looking...